# String.IsEmpty method missing

Tags: c#, .net, string

I'm calling s.IsEmpty() on variable of type string and receive next error:

"Error  CS1061  'string' does not contain a definition for 'IsEmpty' and no accessible extension method 'IsEmpty' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
"

As I understang it doesn't see extension methods, but why?
How can I enable them?

I am using .NET 4.0

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`String.IsEmpty()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.webpages.stringextensions.isempty?view=aspnet-webpages-3.2) is specific to the `System.Web.WebPages` namespace.

You probably meant to use [`String.IsNullOrEmpty()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.isnullorempty?view=net-5.0) or [`String.IsNullOrWhitespace()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.isnullorwhiteSpace?view=netframework-4.0), both of which are part of the `System` namespace.

Comment: To add to this, you can find all methods available on string here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.isnullorempty?view=netframework-4.0

Comment: No, I used s.IsEmpty(). Thank you for the catch about System.Web.WebPages.